# entity framework LIKE query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF4.1 with MySql and unable to get LIKE query working. I want to get list of products where name like app

.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains("app") returns only one product with name Apple. The generated SQL contains LOCATE operator in place of LIKE '%app%'

I tried executing sql command using SqlQuery("select * from product where name like '%@p0%'", "app") but to no avail. It does not retrun any products.

Could some please suggest how can I write LIKE for MySql db. Thanks

Comment: We are with the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know EF (yo no hablo Microsoft), but I bet that the wildcards on your literal are interfering with the parameter replacement.

If you try something like the following, does it help?

```
SqlQuery("select * from product where name like concat('%',@p0,'%')", "app")
```

Is "@p0" the parameter? I assume so.

Also, try:

```
SqlQuery("select * from product where name like '@p0'", "%app%")
```

Also:

```
SqlQuery("select * from product where name like @p0", "'%app%'")
```

I bet one of these will work.